# Как в Intellij Idea сгенерировать геттеры/сеттеры и сразу их использовать вместо переменных в существующем коде?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

До

```
public class Main1 {
    int i;
    String s;

    void a() {
        i = 456;
        s = "Text";
        System.out.println(i + s);
    }
}
```

После

```
public class Main1 {
    int i;
    String s;
    
    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    void a() {
        setI(456);
        setS("Text");
        System.out.println(getI() + getS());
    }
}
```

Как изменить первый код на второй без ручного изменения, в Intellij Idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь рефакториногом `Encapsulate Fields` из меню `Refactor`.

Он позволяет сгенерировать геттеры и сеттеры и заменить использование полей на новые сгенерированные функции.

[image: окно рефакторинга Encapsulate Fields в IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 2):

На Windows с помощью сочетания клавиш alt + insert появится меню генерации. Там можно выбрать создать геттеры и сеттеры как отдельно, так и вместе

Answer (score 1):

Делаем раз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаем два:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово.

---

На счёт строки `System.out.println(getI() + getS());` без ручного вмешательства возможно никак

Comment: Дополню, вдруг не знали: `sout + tab` - System.out.println();